# Summing values based on range of column names using indexing when using apply in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a `df`:

```
id    A1        A2        a    b    c    d
1     50        300       40   0    25   50
2     100       50        50   100  30   100
```

This data represents a warehouse, `A1` is current items in the warehouse, `A2` is how many items is shipped each month, `a, b, c, d` represents months.

I am trying to apply such logic where I calculate stock on each months `b, c, d`:

```
id    A1        A2        a    b    c    d         stock_on_b      stock_on_c      stock_on_d    
1     50        300       40   0    25   50        A1-A2+a+b       A1-A2+a+b+c     A1-A2+a+b+c+d    
2     100       50        50   100  30   100       A1-A2+a+b       A1-A2+a+b+c     A1-A2+a+b+c+d
```

I wrote a function for each month, which looks like this:

```
# stock left on b
def b_stock(x):

    return 0 if x['A2'] > (x['A1'] +  x.loc[:,'a':'b'].sum(axis=1)) 
             else x['A1'] + x.loc[:,'a':'b'].sum(axis=1))

df['stock_on_b'] = df.apply(b_stock, axis=1)
```

But I get an error:

> IndexingError: Too many indexers

I think this is because I am trying to use `.loc` on a row, because `.apply` works on rows and not the whole `df` but I am unsure, how could I apply this logic using column name range instead of writing every single column name in the equation like this

```
return 0 if x['A2'] > (x['A1'] +  x['A1'] + x['a'] + x['b'] + x['c']) 
             else x['A1'] + x['A1'] + x['a'] + x['b'] + x['c'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorized solution with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
s = df.loc[:,'a':'b'].sum(axis=1)
m = df['A2'] > df['A1'] + s 

df['stock_on_b'] = np.where(m, 0, df['A1'] + s)
```

Apply alternative (slowier, because processing per rows):

```
def b_stock(x):
    #x is Series (row, because apply with axis=1)
    #print (x)
    v = x.loc['a':'b'].sum()
    return 0 if x['A2'] > (x['A1'] + v) else x['A1'] + v

df['stock_on_b1'] = df.apply(b_stock, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, as I can see my mistakes was using axis in both `apply` and the `sum`?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - exactly, because if use `apply` then is processing per Series.